# How am I supposed to attach wires in a traditional greenhouse?

Tags: greenhouse

[image]
[image]

I've been given this nice greenhouse. I've always seen other people have wires in theirs to conveniently hold canes etc in place, so I'm surprised I can't see obvious attachment points. I'd imagine the aluminium uprights would have holes drilled or something.

What is the correct way to do this? Are there fittings or an I supposed to just jury rig it?

Comment: Bending them, other than that put it on: https://diy.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find clips and brackets to fix wires to. In the UK, for example, there's this site: http://www.greenhousespares.co.uk/shop/clips-and-brackets. You might also be able to fasten wires to those internal struts we can see in your photos.

Comment: There seem to be numerous parts which 'twist in' to the grooves on the vertical struts. But the corner struts don't have grooves.